# Which of these intensifiers is the larger in its intensity?

Tags: word-choice, word-difference

> He turned back to Harry. "You'll soon find out some wizarding families
>   are **much** better than others, Potter. You don't want to go making
>   friends with the wrong sort.
>  (Harry Potter and the Sorcerer's
>   Stone)
>
> "Unless you get out now," said Harry, more bravely than he felt,
>   because Crabbe and Goyle were **a lot** bigger than him or Ron. 
>   (Harry Potter and the Sorcerer's Stone)

Between the two – much, a lot – which is the bigger in its intensity?

Comment: Neither, really. The distinction is rather one of register than of degree: The first speaker (Malfoy?) employs a somewhat less colloquial term, suggesting a difference of class and upbringing and a more distant relationship.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*A lot* is used with adjectives and adverbs to mean *much*. You could use *a lot* or *much*, and the meaning would be the same.
The difference is that *a lot* is still seen as informal, while *much*, *a great deal of*, or *a large amount of* are allowed in formal writing. (See the grammar notes at the bottom of [this](http://oaadonline.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/much_1) page.)